# If I have installed MinGW and Cygwin (on Windows 7), which one will be used when the gcc compiler is invoked in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, gcc, cmd, cygwin, mingw

If I have installed MinGW and Cygwin (on Windows 7), which one will be used when the gcc compiler is invoked on the Windows MS-DOS shell command line?

If it is ambiguous, how can I figure out which one of the two packages' GCC is used?

Comment: I think it depends on your `%PATH%`.

Comment: The one in the current directory or if not the firstone found in the path. Here's a batch file that searchesforthe exe run. `@echo off
echo. 
echo PathFind - Finds the first file in in a path
echo ======== = ===== === ===== ==== == == = ====
echo. 
echo Searching for %1 in %path%
echo. 
set a=%~$PATH:1
If "%a%"=="" (Echo %1 not found) else (echo %1 found at %a%)
` Specify the extension. So `Pathfind.bat gcc.exe`.

Comment: First one is MinGW. Thank you both.

Comment: `where gcc` may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory serves neither one modifies your system PATH. So if you just open `cmd.exe` you are probably going to get a

```
gcc not found
```

If you want to use GCC you will need to open the Bash prompt for Cygwin or MinGW.

Comment: My MinGW did append to the Path. Thanks in any case.

Comment: I should add that I used a modified MinGW install and since I installed it a long time ago it could easily be that I added it to the Path variable.